# How efficient is reading a big xml file from sdcard?

Tags: android, xml, performance

I've a big XML file(6000 lines, 1.4MB) stored in the `/mnt/sdcard` folder. I want to read one node from the XML file to fetch the version from the file in my Android application.

Since the file is big and stored in sdcard, so will the reading of XML slow down the performance?

Comment: Try it and time it? While not XML I've written an app using a 120MB OSM map file on an SD card and it runs suprisingly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reading and parsing 1.4 MB of XML will take some time (from my experience, I'd estimate between 0.1 and 2 seconds). How much depends on how you do it, and if it's acceptable depends on what you consider acceptable. I'd suggest to just benchmark it yourself.

Also, use a parser like SAX that can stop reading once you have the data. This way, if the version is usually at the beginning, you don't need to read and parse the entire file. If you know that the version is always the first line, performance will probably be very good.

Comment: Version is at the lowest line in the xml. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcpirfuorcvsemz/Manifest.xml?m) is my xml and I'm interested in the version of `<Item Type="ProviderXml"`.

Comment: Then I'd suggest to still use SAX and of course only read the value once and then cache it. If that is too slow and you know that your XML has an exact format and you know that your value is in the last n KB, then you could just read the last n KB and parse it manually (ugly ugly hack).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read only one node, why don't you use [`XPath`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html)?

It may or may not provide performance speedup compared to parsing using SAX or DOM (you need to benchmark it for your case yourself), but it might simplify your code.